# Independent figcaption text settings from the paragraph

Tags: html, css

I have the following paragraphs with image on side and I need a "figcaption" on each image. I need to set the "figcaption" text with independent settings. How can i do this?

Also, I'm not sure if the figcaption tag is correctly used in my HTML:

```
<p><figure><span class="image right"><img src="images/scania_old.jpg" alt="Stoptrans first truck" /><figcaption>Stoptrans first truck in the 80's</figcaption></span></figure>Vestibulum ultrices risus velit, sit amet.</p>
```

[image: Example Image]

My image.right and image.left class have this settings:

```
.image.right {
            float: right;
            margin: 0 0 1em 1.5em;
            top: 0.25em;
        }

.image.left {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 1.5em 1em 0;
            top: 0.25em;
        }
```

And I need my figcaption to use this settings:

```
            font-size: 75%;
            font-style: italic;
            text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat a figcaption tag the same you would do with any other tag by applying style to figcaption type tag or giving it class attribute in your html.

Applying style to figcaption:

```
figcaption {
font-size: 75%;
font-style: italic;
text-align: center;
}
```

Using a class attribute:

```
<figcaption class="example">Stoptrans first truck in the 80's</figcaption>

.example {
font-size: 75%;
font-style: italic;
text-align: center;
}
```